# AWS Fargate cannot access application over Public DNS name

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, aws-fargate, aws-security-group

This is a follow up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63352705/aws-fargate-cannot-access-dockerized-spring-boot-application-over-load-balancer/63370237#63370237). I'm successfully able to access the public IP over fargate. However, after trying to attach Application load balancer, I cannot access application over public DNS. The registered target always show unhealthy status with 502 error.

Sharing my configuration settings-

VPC
[image: VPC]
Route Table Public Subnet
[image: Route Table Public Subnet]
Route Table public subnet config
[image: Route Table public subnet config]
Route Table private subnet
[image: Route Table private subnet]
Route Table private subnet config
[image: Route Table private subnet config]
ACL subnet associations
[image: ACL subnet associations]
ACL inbound rules
[image: ACL inbound rules]
ACL outbound rules
[image: ACL outbound rules]
security inbound rules
[image: security inbound rules]
security outbound rules
[image: security outbound rules]
internet gateway
[image: internet gateway]
nat gateway
[image: nat gateway]
target group
[image: target group]
target group health status
[image: target group health status]
task details
[image: task details]
service
[image: service]
ALB settings
[image: ALB]
ALB listeners
[image: ALB listeners]
Target group with 8081 port
[image: Target group with 8081 port]

Comment: What does the target group for the ALB and the task look like?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams I have attached the screenshot for ALB target group and task details.

Comment: OK, and the security groups for both?

Comment: Please refresh the page, I just added the image tags. Security outbound and inbound rules have been attached.

Comment: I can only see one security group, does your ALB and Task both share the same security group?

Comment: yes the default security group!

Comment: Can you check your target groups. Your containers run on port 8081, but it seems your target group and health checks are set for port 80.

Comment: Also make sure that your health check endpoint does not return a redirect code (302) instead of 200, or any other  code than 200. Otherwise, will have to modify health checks.

Comment: @Marcin, good catch! I changed the target group port to 8081 and also created a new security group with new inbound and outbound rules. I can ping successfully my load balancer DNS name. But the ip address (private ip of the subnet of my vpc) under registered target group still shows unhealthy but with Request timed out status! I overided the health checkpoint port also to 8081 and the status code to return is set  200 by default! I have added a recent screenshot with new target group setting in the question!

Comment: Tasks are still publicly accessible? If you use public IP of your task, without using ALB, the application works?

Comment: no! when I'm using public ip of my task (reference: task details screenshot) and browse public_ip:8081/my_restendpoint, I cannot access it!

Comment: Your HC timeout is 5 seconds. Maybe your container requires more time to respond?

Comment: Double check the public ip access. If the tasks get killed all the time due to failing HCs in a loop, you might have tried accessing it when it was already dead or dying. So first verify that the contains work without ALB, then can trouble shoot the request timeout. Maybe containers are too slow, or don't respond correctly to HCs pings.

Comment: Sadly, I have to finish for now. Please let me know how it will go and I will check later.

Comment: @Marcin I changed the target group settings , updated interval to 130 seconds, timeout to 120 seconds, healthy threshold to 5, unhealthy threshold to 2! Now the health check for registered target return 504 status!

Comment: Something must be happening with the containers, I think. Can you verify they are working? Maybe have to use different endpoint for the HC?

Comment: @Marcin it works now after updating interval time! Bit strange, as it took couple of hours to reflect the changes! Would be curious to know the cause!

Comment: Don't know. Indeed strange. If you don't mind I can provide answer for now?

Comment: @Marcin yes please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

There were **two issues** identified:

1. I**ncorrect port** on the target group. It was `80` instead of `8081`.
2. Healthy threshold **timeout** was too short (5 seconds). Increasing it seemed to solved the issue.

Comment: My target group port was `80` and i changed it to `8080` (my backend is running on `8080`), also increased from 5 seconds to 10 (max limit) for healthy threshold -- still the same result. "This site cna't be reached", domain.com's DNS address could not be found, DNS_PROBE_POSSIBLE